# How many circles can touch a given circle at most in other norms?

Tags: normed-spaces, circles

It is well known that one can place exactly six circles around a circle of same size:

[image: Six unit circles around a blue unit circle]

But that of course depends on the norm, so the answer is (to me at least) only obvious in this trivial case.  How is it for other norms?  I tried it out for the $p$-norm with $p=4$:

[image: Six unit "circles" irregularly around a blue unit "circle"]

It seems that in the case of $p$-norms independent of $p$ the answer is $6$, but this is of course no proof and I'm not sufficiently good at math to proof it correctly myself and I didn't find anything about it on the internet.

Answer (score 2):

Wrt. the max-norm $||.||_{\infty}$ (squares with coord-parallel sides) as well as the LAD-norm $||.||_1$ (squares with sides aligned to the coord diagonals) the answer obviously is 8 (just consider the 3x3 subdivision of a larger square).

--- rk

Comment: Ah, thanks!  That should have been obvious to me.